# rsync ignoring file permissions

Tags: raspberry-pi, rsync

I'm sorting and rationalising my backups to my raspberry pi + ext drive
One is a win10 PC  that I mount

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.92/blah/PC /mnt/PC -o username=xx,password=xx,ro,uid=pi,gid=pi
```

and then the source  directory (eg)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls  -la /mnt/PC/pictures/
total 24284


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt/PC/..../Pictures/2009_07_15/ | grep 70 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 2387027 Jul 15  2009 IMG_0063.JPG
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 2385117 Jul 15  2009 IMG_0070.JPG
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 3457076 Jul 15  2009 IMG_0071.JPG
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

ive rationalised backups so have some pictures in destination from another source 
so the (existing) destination is

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt/seagate/PC/../2009_07_15/ | grep 70 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 2387027 Jul 15  2009 IMG_0063.JPG
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 2385117 Jul 15  2009 IMG_0070.JPG
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 3457076 Jul 15  2009 IMG_0071.JPG
```

when I do

```
rsync -n -vv -rtdiz --no-owner --no-perms --no-group --progress --log-file=/tmp/rsynclog --backup-dir=/mnt/seagate/deletedfiles/backup-2020-01-07 --delete /source /destination
```

it says it will delete the files in 'destination' and then copy the same file from 'source'

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /tmp/rsynclog | grep 2009_07_15
    2020/01/08 11:55:02 [31205] backed up Documents.../2009_07_15/Thumbs.db to /mnt/seagate/deletedfiles/backup-2020-01-08/....2009_07_15/Thumbs.db
    2020/01/08 11:55:02 [31205] backed up Documents..../2009_07_15/IMG_0071.JPG to /mnt/seagate/deletedfiles/backup-2020-01-08/....2009_07_15/IMG_0071.JPG
    etc etc 
2020/01/08 11:56:45 [31205] .d..t...... Documents/.....Pictures/2009_07_15/
2020/01/08 11:56:45 [31205] .f          Documents/..   .2009_07_15/IMG_0061.JPG
2020/01/08 11:56:45 [31205] .f          Documents/../Pictures/2009_07_15/IMG_0062.JPG
2020/01/08 11:56:45 [31205] .f          Documents../Pictures/2009_07_15/IMG_0063.JPG
etc
```

I assume because the permissions are different

OK - i could just chmod all the files  in 'destination' but I'd like to know what ive done wrong in the rsync command .

The difference i have found which could account for the transfers is 
on the source , the mounted windows machine

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/PC/Documents/path,... $ ls -l | grep ALL
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi       0 Jan  1 07:54 ALL PHOTOS
```

on the destination , the seagate attached HD

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/seagate/PC/Documents/path,... $ ls -la | grep ALL
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   20480 Dec 18 22:08 ALL PHOTOS
```

Comment: but i can't chmod the destination files because its a NTFS filesystem. But there are other files elsewhere in the directory structure  with  the same file  permissions,  that arent copied .

Comment: --size-only doesnt change anything